# React-native-fbsdk: Could not find generated setter for class

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, facebook-login

I'm starting to implement facebook-login with ract-native, and i follow as

[React-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

but my App always crash when i click to Login Bottom

and i got " **Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk** " from adb logcat

I have tested on Device and Simulator , same result.
Please help me on this issues.

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem?